# View local IP for connected device on hotspot

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, remote-desktop, tethering

is there a way in which I can view the local IP address for a device connected to the hotspot that I make with my iPhone? I want to do this because I want to view the desktop of a Raspberry Pi that I share my mobile data with using VNC Viewer (and I need its local IP address for this). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First off, if the Pi has an internet connection on your local network, you can connect to it with it's hostname, not just it's IP.
This is verified on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=228641

But, if you still need the IP... here's a way:

This is what I did to find out my iphone's hotspot IP.

1. Turn on the hotspot, and connect your Mac to it.
2. Hold down the option key on the Mac, and click your wifi menu icon.

- this will show you extra data like the Gateway address.
- if your Mac and the PI are the only two things using the hotspot, then it should just increment the next number
  *(my mac is 172.20.10.7, so the PI would likely be .8, etc.)*

[image: ip address]

But if not, you have the IP and the Gateway to investigate.

3. Connect the PI to the hotspot.
4. You can then use your mac to run an ip scan of all devices on the same ip range

- Open Terminal on your Mac, and type `arp -a` to get a list of connected IPs on the same network.

[image: ARP on PC]

Of course, if you want to get a bit technical, there are ways to make the Pi tell you it's IP address when it connects.
For example, having it run this command will report back it's known IP: `curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'`

With that, you could have it send an email or tweet the ip anytime it connected to wifi. But that's another reply, I suppose.

Answer (score -3):

`ifconfig` should tell you a lot of information

Comment: How specifically can ifconfig be used to see the IP addresses of devices connected to an iPhone hotspot?

Comment: OP hasnt provided any information the OS of "device1". regardless, `ifconfig` works on windows, macos and linux. if they are running raspberry pi, they should be able to connect a monitor and run the command. RTFM.

Comment: Please reread the question, it starts with „is there a way in which I can view the local IP address for a device connected to the hotspot that I make with my iPhone?“. They can‘t connect to the Pi unless they know its IP address.

Comment: Also, people come to AD because they did RTFM but can‘t solve the problem. So telling them to RTFM is actually rather rude.